# How do you understand the cause of exception having stacktrace?

Tags: android, stack-trace, nullpointerexception

We have written an Android application which sends stack traces to our server, if any occur. Sometimes we get weird stack traces that seem not to be an exception from our application. For example:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.FastScroller.scrollTo1(FastScroller.java:306)
at android.widget.FastScroller.onTouchEvent(FastScroller.java:507)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:1894)
at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3083)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3386)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:831)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1710)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1197)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1993)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1694)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1525)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3952)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There is no mention of our own classes, only Android's standard classes. It's obvious that this exception takes place when scrolling of item list (ListView) occurs, but I can't even uderstand how I can fix this bug. I can't reproduce this bug. What do you usually do when you encounter the same problem? Any ideas?

Comment: My guess, granted without very much evidence, is that you leaked a resource, or are trying to call touch methods on a view that has been destroyed.

Comment: Does your exception upload also send the exception in the "cause" field of the Throwable?  Does your app display anything related to dialing?  Do you have any idea why ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent appears 5 times in a row?  What version of Android are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tehere is something wrong with fast scrolling of some ListView using a thumb. If you set fast scrolling enabled of your `ListView` make sure the adapter class implements `SectionIndexer`.

Comment: "The adapter attached to the list may want to implement SectionIndexer if it wishes to display alphabet preview and jump between sections of the list". So I have no need to implement SectionIndexer, don't I?